# How to make two columns of a table requiring to be unique at user request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have tried validating the user request like this:

```php
$data = $request->validate([
    'fname' => 'nullable',
    'lname' => 'nullable',
    'gender' => 'required',
    'mobile' => 'required|unique:users,usr_name',
    'ncode' => 'nullable',
    'password' => 'required',
    'password_confirmation' => 'required',
]);
```

That the `mobile` filed value must be `unique:users,usr_name` but I do need to check that it is unique at `members` table as well (the `mbr_mobile` column):

```php
unique:members,mbr_mobile
```

So how to combine these two rules at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specifying the model name should work.

```
'mobile' => 'required|unique:User|unique:Members',
```

But you may specify the column name too.

```
'mobile' => 'required|unique:User, mobile|unique:Member,mbr_mobile',
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it exact,y same way as for users table :

```
$data = $request->validate([
        'fname' => 'nullable',
        'lname' => 'nullable',
        'gender' => 'required',
        'mobile' => 'required|unique:users,usr_name|unique:members,mbr_mobile',
        'ncode' => 'nullable',
        'password' => 'required',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required',
    ]);
```